# Remote Address is changing automatically in Angular 6 After some ideal time

Tags: angular

we are facing some new issue with angular 6, our project is developed in angular 6 with backend spring-boot with OAuth 2.0. Initially, when we deployed the application and open the page in the browser everything seems fine but after some idle time( kept the page idle) without any operations and perform some operation after some time, before calling any POST method, angular is calling OPTIONS Method , while calling the OPTIONS method the Remote address is changing to local IP where we deploy the Angular code instead of Rest Services IP and we also getting CROS issue only after idle time. if anyone has faced this issue in your project, pls help me out to resolve it.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9YhZ.png)

Comment: First of all there is nothing wrong with OPTION request and can tell us your backend is maintained in which language?

Comment: we are using spring-boot(API are exposed as REST Services) with OAuth 2.0 for authentication.

Answer (score 0):

We found the solution, the problem is with Angular JS, so PWA(progressive web applications) a thread will be created and the application will be running on it. so every request it first pulls the data from Cache and then sends a req to back end. so we need to stop the req to get the data from Cache and pull it directly from the backend.

So angular configurations need to be done to ngsw.json, there is a section called dataGroups, there we need to use "strategy": "freshness" instead of performance ()

"dataGroups": [{
    "name": "api-freshness",
    "urls": [
    ],
    "cacheConfig": {
      "maxSize": 100,
      "maxAge": "1h",
      "timeout": "10s",
      "strategy": "freshness"
    }
  }, {
    "name": "api-performance",
    "urls": [
      "/", **//not caching**
      "/home", **//not caching**
      "/snack" **//not caching**
    ],
    "cacheConfig": {
      "maxSize": 100,
      "maxAge": "1h",
      "strategy": "performance"
    }
  }]